# Plot one figure at a time without closing old figure (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, backend, figure

Is there a way to plot a set of figures one at a time without closing the previous figure, maintaining control of the UI, and keeping the figures open at the end? Perhaps using a more appropriate backend, or writing it using the OO style instead of the pyplot/pylab style used below?

e.g. I know I can do

```
plt.ioff()
for i in range(10)
    plt.figure()
    arr = thisFunctionTakesTenSecondsToGenerateMyArray()
    plt.plot(arr)
    plt.show()
```

which will wait for me to close the figure at every iteration

I can also do

```
plt.ion()
for i in range(10)
    plt.figure()
    arr = thisFunctionTakesTenSecondsToGenerateMyArray()
    plt.plot(arr)
```

which will plot them as fast as it can generate them (e.g. 10 secs) but will block my entire UI (e.g. I can't even move the windows around), won't show the axes (I only see the figure window), and also will automatically close all the figures at the end of the loop.

The third option that I'm not looking for is this

```
plt.ioff()
for i in range(10)
    plt.figure()
    arr = thisFunctionTakesTenSecondsToGenerateMyArray()
    plt.plot(arr)
plt.show()
```

which involves waiting 100 seconds before seeing anything on my screen.

I'm looking for behavior similar to Matlab where I can do

```
for i = 1:10
    figure()
    arr = thisFunctionTakesTenSecondsToGenerateMyArray()
    plot(arr)
    drawnow
```

which will draw a figure every 10 seconds, and also allow me to move the windows around e.g. if fig 3 is on top and I want to go back to fig 1 while fig 4 is being generated.

Edit:
Using Python 2.7.13, Matplotlib 2.0.0. Running it using Spyder 3.1.3 on Windows 7 SP1 - I've tried running it in the built-in IPython console, the vanilla Python console, and from a script all with the same results.

Ideally, I would like to be able to run it both from a script and interactively, i.e. by executing a script or by copying and pasting into the console.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: do you want to run the code from an interactive python session or from a command line ?

Comment: @Astrom Python 2.7.13, Matplotlib 2.0.0 (updated the original question)

Comment: @ab-user216125 Ideally, both, but I'll take a solution for either one.

Answer (score 2):

just add `plt.pause(0.0001)` inside the loop after `plt.show(block=False)`, and a final `plt.show()` at the end in case you are executing the script from the operating system command line.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for, but it still blocks (or perhaps just freezes) the UI so that I can't do anything during the 10 seconds that `arr = thisFunctionTakesTenSecondsToGenerateMyArray()` is executing. e.g. if I move the first window those 10 seconds, it will actually place the second window in the new location, and keep the first one where it was.

Also, it only works if I'm running the entire script (i.e. from a command line) but not from a Python console.

Comment: ok, now I am a bit confused. Do you want to do animation, or do you need to plots to interactively modify them while the script is running? If not, then just let the script finish and you will have all plots separately for tweaking. If you just need all plots, you could save each figure as they are generated `plt.savefig()` and then you can look at then in an image viewer. 
While a program is running you can not actually modify it. If you need for some reason to operate in the same interactive session check out the `subprocess` module  https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I just want the figures to pop up as soon as they are generated so that I don't have to wait for all of them to finish plotting before I do anything. For example, I might realize that something is going wrong by the time the 2nd figure appears and can kill the loop so I don't have to waste time waiting for the other 8 figures to finish. Your suggestion gets me some of the way there, but I would also like the ability to move the figure windows around while the script is running. This is how Matlab behaves out-of-the-box, and they are probably doing some multiprocess magic as you suggest

Comment: in that case the fastest way to inspect the plot is to save it instead of making it plot on the screen. I haven't checked now, but you can time it. You can even write a condition to stop and continue the calculations if you are ok with a single plot. If you need a python session to work while your code is running, just open another terminal and python session. or put your code in a script and run from command line with `&` at the end, which makes the linux terminal free