# Dynamically update plot Matplotlib Python (for unsteady heat diffusion)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python and trying to do what have been doing in MATLAB for so long. My current challenge is to dynamically update a plot without drawing a new figure in a for or while loop. I am aware there are similar questions and answers but most of them are too complicated and I believe it should be easier. 
I got the example from here
https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-update-plot/
But I can't see the figure, no error, no nothing. I added two lines just to see if I can see the static plot and I can.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

# This is just a test just to see if I can see the plot window
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')



for phase in np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100):
    line1.set_ydata(np.sin(0.5 * x + phase))
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Any idea why I can't see the dynamic plot? 
Thank you 
Erdem

Comment: What happens when you add `plt.show` to the end of the `for` loop?

Comment: I did, nothing. I can see it is working but no plot window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `plt.pause(0.0001)` inside the loop after `plt.show(block=False)`, and a final `plt.show()` outside the loop. This should work fine with `plt.ion()`; ref to some older answers [Plot one figure at a time without closing old figure (matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420096/plot-one-figure-at-a-time-without-closing-old-figure-matplotlib/43420596#43420596)